# How to find the sum of elements in row in grid

Tags: extjs

I want to transpose a grid and display the sum row-wise. The sum should be displayed at the end of the row or at any mentioned positioned.

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.grid.plugin.Summary.html check this out..

Comment: it will find the sum coloumn wise only and my need is of row wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For row-wise sum, Add extra column for grid.

```
{
   text: 'Total',            
   dataIndex: 'total'
}
```

and write a convert function for total in your model returning sum of all your fields.

```
{
    name: 'total', 
    convert: function(value, record) {
        return record.get('field1') + record.get('field2') + record.get('field3');
    }
}
```